# An issue with reading files using Pydub AudioSegment

Tags: python, pydub, audiosegment

I am very new to Pydub library and having trouble with some functionalities.

I'm trying to provide an audio file in same directory to the AudioSegment.from_file() function and it keeps returning this error,

```
File "c:/Users/Win 10/Desktop/Final Year Project/wav_error_test.py", line 51, in <module>     
    timestamps = audioClipping(path)
  File "c:/Users/Win 10/Desktop/Final Year Project/wav_error_test.py", line 30, in audioClipping
    newAudio = AudioSegment.from_mp3(song)
  File "C:\Users\Win 10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 796, in from_mp3
    return cls.from_file(file, 'mp3', parameters=parameters)
  File "C:\Users\Win 10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 728, in from_file
    info = mediainfo_json(orig_file, read_ahead_limit=read_ahead_limit)
  File "C:\Users\Win 10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py", line 274, in mediainfo_json
    res = Popen(command, stdin=stdin_parameter, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
  File "C:\Users\Win 10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\Win 10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I'm also receiving a run time warning for ffmpeg even after I add it into my PATH,

```
RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffprobe or avprobe - defaulting to ffprobe, but may not work
  warn("Couldn't find ffprobe or avprobe - defaulting to ffprobe, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)
```

And finally I'll provide the code snippet.

```
def audioClipping(song):
    AudioSegment.converter = which('ffmpeg')
    newAudio = AudioSegment.from_file(song,"mp3")

path ='Viyona - Ranga Weerasekara Ft. Harsha Priyashan.mp3'
timestamps = audioClipping(path)
```

It would be grate if some one can simply explain what to do here. Thank you